# About holomorphic functions on the upper half plane with respect to SO(2).

Tags: complex-analysis, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the upper half plane. For $g=\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right) \in SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $z \in \mathbb{H}$, set $J(g,z)=cz+d$. Let $SO(2)$ be the special orthogonal group. For a positive integer $k$, define $H_k(\mathbb{H})$ to be
$$
H_k(\mathbb{H})=\{f:\mathbb{H} \stackrel{holomorphic}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{C}|f(xz)=J(x,z)^kf(z),{}^\forall x \in SO(2)\}.
$$

I guess that $H_k(\mathbb{H})$ is zero. But I have no proof of that. Could you tell me the proof that $H_k(\mathbb{H})$ is zero (or not)? Is this well-known? If so, tell me related publications for such functions.

Comment: Do you mean $SL_2$ or $SO_2$ in the definition of $H_k$? If the former, then this is slightly weaker than the definition of a modular form, and those exist -- see Eisenstein series for example.

Comment: @Astyx I mean exactly SO(2). I consider similar functions to modular forms replacing the condition on discrete subgroup by that on the special orthogonal group SO(2).

Comment: anything unclear?

Answer (score 0):

For all $c,d\in \Bbb{R}^2-(0,0)$ and $\Im(z)>0$
$$f(\frac{dz-c}{cz+d})= (\frac{cz+d}{\sqrt{c^2+d^2}})^kf(z)$$

By analytic continuation it stays true for all $\Im(z) > 0,c,d\in \Bbb{C}^2, cz+d\ne 0, c^2+d^2\ne 0,\Im(\frac{dz-c}{cz+d}) >0$.

The point is that if $z = ir, r > 0, f(z)\ne 0$ then the RHS has a singularity at $c=1,d=i$
while the LHS doesn't.

So it must be that $f$ vanishes on the imaginary axis, whence it vanishes everywhere.

Comment: What do you mean the equation in the 2nd line? It seems that f in your proof is not an element of $H_k(\mathbb{H})$. Do you give an answer for my question in more general setting?

Comment: @AAA No, I am just dividing $(c,d)$ by $\sqrt{c^2+d^2}$ to make it the bottom row of a $SO_2$ matrix

Comment: I'm catching on.  The sentence ''if $z=ir,r>0, f(z) \not=0$ then'' in 5th line means ''if there exists $r>0$ such that $f(ir) \not=0$, then'', right? Not ''for any $r>0$''.

Comment: If you want yes